# pass variable through XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml-parsing

How can I pass a variable to the server side by using GET?
and how can I use it?

I want to send the params "bar" to the server side and use it in a function but I don't know how to access it at the server side, any pointers?

javascript

```
function update(){
     var params = "bar";
     var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
     req.open("GET","/results"+"?"+params);
     req.onreadystatechange = function(foo){
        if(req.readyState == 4){
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = req.responseText;
           }
      }
    req.send(null);
   }
```

server node.js

```
app.get("/results",function(req,res){
    console.log(req + req.params +req.body)
    getResults(function(results, req){       
        res.writeHead(200,"OK",{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
       res.end(results);
    });
});
```

console

```
[object Object][object Object][object Object]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you trying to pass an empty parameter "bar" to the server? 
I believe that bar should carry a value to make more sense.

So in your client-side code, try:

```
function update () {
    var params = "bar=foo";
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.open("GET","/results?"+params);
    req.onreadystatechange = function (foo) {
        if (req.readyState == 4){
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = req.responseText;
        }
    }
    req.send(null);
}
```

And in your server-side, assuming that you're using express.js (it seems so), you can simply:

```
app.get("/results", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.param("bar"));

    res.send(req.param("bar"));
});
```

And now you will get "foo" in your node.js console as well inside your "content" item at the HTML page.

Try to read more about express.js in their official guide and API docs http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html that I am pretty sure you will get around these questions you will get during the beginning of your journey.

Hope it helps.